# MATLAB: find midpoint between two mismatching time-series

Tags: matlab, time, time-series

In MATLAB (R2015b) I have to find the midpoint between two time series of different lengths (ca 2000 vs. 3000 rows), in both series the first column is time and second is a measurement. Such as `A`:

```
09:30:14 23
09:31:03 23.5
```

And `B`:

```
09:30:19 25.5
09:30:37 25    
09:31:12 24.5
```

How can I get MATLAB to calculate the midpoint value between `A` and `B` and get the result as shown below?

```
09:30:19 24.25     (Here it is 23+(25.5-23)/2)
09:30:37 24        (Here it is 23+(25-23)/2)
09:30:12 24        (Here it is 23.5+(24.5-23.5)/2)
```

Comment: FWIW, vectors of a couple thousand points each aren't especially large.

Comment: Ok, edited it! I'm still pretty new to MATLAB and numerical stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `interp1` function to estimate the value of one series at the time points corresponding to the other samples.  Then the time points agree and you can just take the mean of the values.

`interp1` supports several interpolation methods, such as nearest and linear.

Comment: For future readers; as suggested above, 'nearest' will make the interpolation go step-wise rather than just draw a straight line between two points.